# Flex: What's the difference between an MXML "Component" and an MXML "Module"?

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

As the title suggests, what's the difference between a "Component" (New –> MXML Component) and a "Module" (New –> MXML Module)?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Modules are compiled into SWFs and loaded at runtime with ModuleLoader, whereas MXML components are compiled into an application.  From the Flex docs:

> Modules are SWF files that can be
>   loaded and unloaded by an application.
>   They cannot be run independently of an
>   application, but any number of
>   applications can share the modules.
>
> Modules let you split your application
>   into several pieces, or modules. The
>   main application, or shell, can
>   dynamically load other modules that it
>   requires, when it needs them. It does
>   not have to load all modules when it
>   starts, nor does it have to load any
>   modules if the user does not interact
>   with them. When the application no
>   longer needs a module, it can unload
>   the module to free up memory and
>   resources. [...]
>
> Modules are similar to Runtime Shared
>   Libraries (RSLs) in that they separate
>   code from an application into
>   separately loaded SWF files. Modules
>   are much more flexible than RSLs
>   because modules can be loaded and
>   unloaded at run time and compiled
>   without the application.

Hope that helps!